# The view basket.views.basket_remove didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

**Can someone explain me why am i getting this error?**

I am creating online store in which basket functionality depends on sessionid in cookies.

Look, I have a function `basked_add` on every product in store, which adds specified product to basket and it works correctly without any issues.

I have also a function `basket_delete` in basket to remove specified product from basket, and somehow it doesn't work correctly. And this is the main reason why i made this question.

Function `basket_delete` is called by JQuery like that (equal to `basked_add`):

**1.**
*basket.html*

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove-button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url "basket:basket_delete" %}',
            data: {
                productid: $('#add-button').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
                action: 'post',
            },
            success: function (json) {
    
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {}
        });
    })
```

**2.**
*basket > urls.py*

```
app_name = 'basket'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.basket, name='basket'),
    path('add/', views.basket_add, name='basket_add'),
    path('delete/', views.basket_delete, name='basket_delete'),
]
```

**3.**
Then function is getting executed

*basket > views.py*

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from basket.basket import Basket

def basket_delete(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
        basket.delete(product=product_id)
        response = JsonResponse({'Success': True})
        return response
```

*basket > context_processors.py*

```
from .basket import Basket


def basket(request):
    return {'basket': Basket(request)}
```

*basket > basket.py*

```
class Basket():
   def delete(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)

        if product_id in self.basket:
            del self.basket[product_id]

        self.session.modified = True
```

In console occurs error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/basket/delete/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

And at url http://127.0.0.1:8000/basket/delete/ debug from django:

> The view basket.views.basket_delete didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

**The most weird thing in it is fact that `basked_add` is not rendering any view either, and it works correct, but for `basket_delete` error occurs.**

*basked_add view*

```
def basket_add(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
        quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        size = int(request.POST.get('size'))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        basket.add(product=product, quantity=quantity, size=size)
        basket_quantity = basket.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({'quantity': basket_quantity})
        return response
```

Comment: The condition `if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':` is false, so you do not return a response...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but in script I specified in data that "action: 'post'" and for basked_add it works, so why somehow it shouldn't for basked_delete

Comment: can you `print(request.POST)` (before the `if`). Normally the keys are converted to uppercase

Comment: Yes, i can @WillemVanOnsem ```<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['IjEtvPLymWeRZZG3V0DNlxgOsjXVvviZiBCkE1RMt4B0JROE7AkX4yzhPsOSpvq1'], 'action': ['post']}>```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return at least a default response if the code doesn't come to the conditioned block.

Try like this:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from basket.basket import Basket

def basket_delete(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('productid'))
        basket.delete(product=product_id)
        response = JsonResponse({'Success': True})
        return response
     return JsonResponse('details': 'There is no action key in post request')
```

Just modify the code based on your business case and to avoid the error, you have to at least make return a default response if there is no condition matched.